# CSV to Markdown table

Tags: elisp-macros, formatting, markdown, csv

Say we have a CSV in a buffer:

```
foo,bar,hello
1,234,95
8923,901,145
```

Are there any native Emacs or Markdown-mode built-ins in Emacs that can be used to convert it to a Markdown table? It looks like the syntax is quite different:

```
| Tables        | Are           | Cool  |
| ------------- |:-------------:| -----:|
| col 3 is      | right-aligned | $1600 |
| col 2 is      | centered      |   $12 |
| zebra stripes | are neat      |    $1 |
```

Comment: Would a series of regex replacements work, or do you want something less general?

Comment: An idea:  select the region containing the csv content, then `M-x org-table-create-or-convert-from-region` (to do this org mode should be enabled), in this way you obtain an org-table. Then there is the command `M-x org-md-export-as-markdown`. I am not sure if this output is the one you would like to obtain.

Answer (score 2):

The [Melpa package archive](https://melpa.org) has `markdown-mode`. My currently installed version is `markdown-mode-20180115.1905`.
If you have [added melpa to `package-archives` correctly](https://melpa.org/#/getting-started) you can install `markdown-mode` via <kbd>M-x</kbd> `package-install`.

After installation of `markdown-mode` files with extension `.md` are opened in `markdown-mode`.

If that mode is activated you find the submenu `Tables` in the `Markdown` menu.
In there you find the menu item `Convert Region to Table`.

If you click that item after selecting the cvs table as region the cvs table is converted to a markdown table.

It is easy to add a header line.
Just insert a newline after the first line, type `|-` and press <kbd>Tab</kbd>.
The initial string `|-` is expanded to a full header line.

You only need to add the colons `:` yourself.
Each time you modify the table in that way you can re-balance the table by pressing <kbd>Tab</kbd>.

Comment: It's nice to learn about this feature. You might add (for those who don't use Menus) that the actual command is `markdown-table-convert-region` and is bound by default to `C-c C-c |`

Answer (score 0):

You can easy to convert CSV To Markdown Table at [tableconvert.com](https://tableconvert.com/?output=markdown)，

Step 1. Click Import button and paste your valid csv data.

Step 2. Choose markdown output.

At the same time, your csv has been converted to markdown, you can copy the results to the clipboard